# How to send variables over the network with multiplayer in java?

Tags: java, multiplayer

Everytime a player connects with the server, I want the server to add 1 to variable: connectedPlayers and send it to all the clients who are connected with this server.
With one player it is working fine, the server sends 1 to my client.
But when I connect with another client, things get wired, connectedPlayers is now: 2 on the server-side BUT on the client-side it is: 514, 33554434, 0, 2, 33554432, 16777216.

Some code that I'm using:

```java
user = new ArrayList<Users>();
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7777);
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();
```

and in the run method in a while(true) loop:

```java
socket = serverSocket.accept();
connectedPlayers++;
user.add(null);
for(int i = 0; i < connectedPlayers; i++){
    if(user.get(i) == null){
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        user.set(i, new Users(out, in, i));
        Thread thread = new Thread(user.get(i));
        thread.start();
        break;
    }
}
```

The Users class is also a Runnable implemented class and does this:

```
//reveive some stuff
for(int i = 0; i < connectedPlayers; i++){
    if(user.get(i) != null){
        //send some other stuff
        user.get(i).out.writeInt(connectedPlayers); //out = DataOutputStream
    }
}
```

And in the Client class(imlplements Runnable) I send some things to the server, and I got another class(implements Runnable) in the Client class which receives data:

```java
//send stuff to Server in the client class

//in the second class in the run method in a while loop
int playerid = in.readInt();
int x = in.readInt();
int y = in.readInt();
int image = in.readInt();
int status = in.readInt();
int connectedPlayer = in.readInt();
client.update(playerid, x, y, image, status, connectedPlayer);
```

What to change to get this working, all help is really appreciated.
If this is all too much code and stuff, tell me and I'll be happy to change it!

Thanks in advance, Joeri.

Comment: Are tou getting any exceptions ?

Comment: No I'm not... @sunrise76

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32293577/broadcasting-to-multiple-clients-using-tcp-connection-in-java/32293649#32293649

Comment: Thankyou, ill have a look!

Comment: You can send object via ObjectOutputStream apis. Since we do not know what other stuff you are sending,difficult to predict output behaviour.

Comment: Just sending integers for pos and an integer for in which direction the player is facing

Comment: Using objects instead of plain data types is helpful to understand which integer maps what value.

Comment: You are writing the connected players to yourself as well as to all the other players.